# How to tell if my beardie is girl or boy

Tags: bearded-dragon

Some one please help me and my girlfriend can't figure out wether this is a boy or a girl[image][image]

Comment: please add some more information to your question.

Comment: Welcome to pets SE Michael! Please check out the answer I duped this question on, this will help you out :)